# SQL Server 2014 crash on Linked Server query

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, sql-server-2014, linked-server

I've been having a recurring issue when attempting to query large results from a linked server. I am using SQL Server 2014 and have a POSTGRESQL Server setup as a Linked Server. I have no problem querying against the Linked server on basic/small results or functions. But on the larger jobs the query will attempt to run for a few minutes and eventually the SQL Server will crash and SSMS will produce this error:

```
A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - The pipe has been ended.)
```

Here is the version of SQL Server 2014 that I am currently on. I have found that there was a bug regarding this or at least something similar in Windows Server 2012 and had a hotfix but that doesn't apply to my build (Attempted to apply anyways). The OS being used is Windows Server 2016.

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP1-GDR) (KB4019091) - 12.0.4237.0 (X64) 
    Jul  5 2017 22:03:42 
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
    Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor)
```

Has anyone else had this issue? I have TCP/IP, Named Pipes, and Shared Memory enabled in my SQL Server Configuration Manager already and my Linked Server Provider currently has these options enabled: Dynamic parameter, Allow inprocess, Non transacted updated.

UPDATED INFORMATION:

I have checked through some additional potential causes including 32-bit registry key issues and local user issues. I am still encountering this same issue after these changes as well.

```
Date        8/28/2017 2:32:24 PM
Log     Windows NT (Application)

Source      Application Error
Category        (100)
Event       1000
Computer        DBM

Message
Faulting application name: sqlservr.exe, version: 2014.120.4237.0, time stamp: 0x595e7459
Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 10.0.14393.1532, time stamp: 0x5965abad
Exception code: 0xc0000374
Fault offset: 0x00000000000f8363
Faulting process id: 0x13c0
Faulting application start time: 0x01d32034049e1344
Faulting application path: E:\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.ESCENTRAL\MSSQL\Binn\sqlservr.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
Report Id: 3489af8e-639f-4a54-ac3e-fda719cf75dc
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

This is the application error that I am seeing in my SQL Logs when the crash occurs

Comment: This is a known issue. See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2859413/sql-server-service-crashes-when-you-run-a-linked-server-query-on-a-win for a description of the problem and a resolution.

Comment: As I stated in my question, "I have found that there was a bug regarding this or at least something similar in Windows Server 2012 and had a hotfix but that doesn't apply to my build (Attempted to apply anyways)" I am running Windows Server 2016 and this hotfix will not even apply to my system.

Comment: Do you mean the actual SQL Server service will crash or just the query? Have you checked query time out settings?

Comment: Check the SQL Log.  Frequently this is caused by a bug in the 3rd party OleDB/ODBC library crashing SQL Server.

Comment: @Alex Yes, the SQL Server service will crash and I have to manually go into Services.msc to start the service back up and the SQL Agent as well.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I will look into the logs more closely as I replicate this error. Currently I do not see anything in the logs about the crash or errors that I can see.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Looks like there may be an issue with SQL Server Agent when running the Stored Procedure. [396] An idle CPU condition has not been defined - OnIdle job schedules will have no effect. I am looking further into this error now.